# IExplorer 11 y Bootstrap 4 al hacer foco en input dentro de una ventana modal me la redimensiona en alto

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

Tengo una aplicación con un botón que al pulsarlo aparece una ventana modal con un input. Al hacer foco en el input para rellenarlo con texto la ventana modal se me redimensiona en alto. Estoy usando Bootstrap 4 en IExplorer 11. Con otros navegadores como Firefox, Chrome, Opera o Edge funciona bien pues no me hace este efecto.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalAdd" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalAdd">AÑADIR DATO</h5> 
      <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
    </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
        <label for ="inputDato">Dato</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDato" placeholder="Entra dato" />
     </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" >Guardar cambios</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Échale un ojo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377501/how-to-vertically-align-bootstrap-v4-modal-dialogs